# Class selector not working

Tags: jquery

I'm doing z-index management by class .. so the active object gets the class topmost ..

```
function topmost() {
    $(".topmost").removeClass("topmost");
    $("#thing").addClass("topmost");
}
```

This code doesn't seem to be working, and I can't fathom why ..

== EDIT ==

The problem is that `$(".topmost").removeClass("topmost");` is finding zero results when there are several on the page. I use this class selector often and have never had this issue. The class is being added by jQuery in the first place, but it should see it anyway. I look in my inspector and log the selection and it comes up with zero when I can see the at least 3 divs with the class. It is a function nested in an object, is that a problem? Can it scope out of the object and search the whole DOM?

Comment: How is the function supposed to know what the `object` refers to? Where is it defined?

Comment: @DavidThomas holy crap , Dave Thomas  - awesome name!

Comment: @ScottSelby: I'll pass your regards on to my parents..! =)

Comment: Define "not working". Does the topmost class not get removed, does it not get added? Both??

Comment: @DavidThomas to do so: $('#me').parent().text('regards from Scott'); :-p

Comment: @Gustonez, I hate to say it, but I think you've maybe spent too much time at your computer today... =D

Comment: Edited my post to better reflect the problem ..

Comment: html and also where are you calling this function?

Comment: if possible a jsfiddle will help

Comment: Do I need to use something like live() or on() ?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/3Dbf4/

Comment: try creating the appending the div with jquery with the class, then removing it

Comment: @KirkStrobeck are you talking about something like this then? http://jsfiddle.net/MPT3z/

Comment: @wirey mark that as an answer and i'll award it .. unfortunately it doesnt fix my issue .. clearly my issue cant be replicated here ..

Comment: @KirkStrobeck I put it up as an answer.. is your page live?  If it is, share the link and maybe I can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are inserting elements after the dom loads?  If so you need to delegate the event to a parent element that exists in the dom.

```
$('body').on('click','div', function() {
    $('.topmost').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('topmost');
});
```

`body` can be replaced with the closest parent element the exists on dom ready

One last thing, always wrap your event binding inside a `$(document).ready` function or place the script at the bottom of your html code to ensure elements exist at the time of binding.

Here's an example fiddle of it working

http://jsfiddle.net/MPT3z/

Here's how to apply the click event to all elements

```
$('body').on('click','*', function() {
    $('.topmost').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('topmost');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eLDpn/

Comment: What if i wanted it for any element that had the class, not just a div `'*'` ?

Comment: Oh I just used `div` as a generic holder.. you don't need the `*`.. just replace with the class selector `.yourclass`

Comment: Can you show me? im not sure i understand .. And why wouldn't just colling the class work, can you explain the scope issue here and what jquery isnt doing?

Comment: Its because if the element doesn't exist the first time the dom loads - then it's not able to bind the event to the element -  How can it bind an event handler to an element that doesn't exist at that time?  So by delegating - the event handler is bound to the parent element - in my example is the `body`, that always exist when the dom is ready.  When you click on the element with your "class selector", the event will bubble up and the body will handle the event.  You can just use class selector and bind the click if you can guarantee that the elements will exist when the dom is loaded

Comment: Thanks ! One last thing .. could you please add an example where it includes all elements, not just `div`s ?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck  sure.. can you tell me what exactly is triggering your function `topMost()`?  is it an onclick? onchange? hover?  And you want all elements with a certain class correct?  what is that class?  or is it `all` elements on your page?

Comment: `onclick` and then reversing on `onrelease` it can be applied to any element including a `div`

Comment: I think I finally realized what it is .. I needed to use `jquery each`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
         $(document).on('click', '#SELECTOR', function(){
             $(".topmost").removeClass("topmost");
              $(this).addClass("topmost");
         });
```

Where i put #SELECTOR , change that to whatever elements you want this to apply to

object could even go there , assuming that is properly defined to select what you intended

Comment: Can you explain the need for the document wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved pretty easily.. Give the element an ID. And use the ID as a selector.

```
function topmost() {
    $("#myDiv").removeClass("topmost");
    $("#myDiv").addClass("topmost");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function topmost(el) {
    $(".topmost").removeClass("topmost");
    if ($(el).length > 0) {
       $(el).addClass("topmost");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to debug things if you add .each to your selector:

```
function topmost() {
  $(".topmost").each(function() {
    console.log("yo");
    $(this).removeClass("topmost");
  });
  $("#thing").addClass("topmost");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a postback occurring  on the page when you are calling this function??